# Check array is empty

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array like that:

```
json_encode($a) = {"p123_04":[]}
```

How to check that its empty or not?

```
count($a) = int(1)
empty((array)$a) = false
```

What else should I use to check [] is empty or not?

Comment: Are the 2 things you have suggested not enough?

Comment: Your array is not empty, it has a key and an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this

```
if(count($array) > 0)
{
    echo 'Error';
}
else
{
    echo 'No Error';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
empty((array)$a = false
```

Is more than enough to check if an array is empty

Answer (score 0):

@MaoStream simply like you have to check empty() with the parent key:

```
<?php
$a = json_decode('{"p123_04":[]}', true);
if(!empty($a["p123_04"])){
    echo "not empty";
}
else{
    echo "empty";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you wanna absolutely be sure that it is an *empty* *array*, maybe you could go for :

```
if (is_array($array) && ($array === [])){
    // The array is empty
}
```

But maybe it's overkill, if you are sure that it is an array, you can get rid of the first part